# initialized empty git repository

Tags: git, heroku, version-control

i tried first sample Facebook App on Heroku in this command prompt i write like this

```
1)$git remote  
2)$git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:stellent.git
```

responses like this

```
not a repository (or any of the parent directories): git
```

i enter `$git init`  response is

```
initialized  empty git repository in C
```

Is there any way to find correct responces

thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a directory and go into it:

```
mkdir project
cd !$
```

initialize this as a git repo

```
git init
```

now you can run your remote commands

Answer (score 2):

Did you clone your application first?  If you did, it would have created a directory - issue the `git remote` command while in that directory. I'm guessing you're following the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook)?

Comment: See the instructions in the article I reference